# Push Array in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

How to push **array in array** via using Javascript ?

I know only push normal array like...

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(['one','two','three']);
```

That is..

```
array(
 'one',
 'two',
 'three'
)
```

**But what about ? How to push like this...**

```
array(
 array(
  'one',
  'one_two'
 ),
 'two',
 'three'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what you are doing already.

This code makes a single array:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push('one','two','three'); // push three items
```

I.e. the same result as:

```
var arr = ['one','two','three'];
```

This code makes a jagged array (an array in an array):

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(['one','two','three']); // push one item that is an array
```

I.e. the same result as:

```
var arr = [
  ['one','two','three']
];
```

Comment: @Guffa that was clear for me to know what I just did. As OP was interested in pushing the array in an array I did that. Thanks you. +1.

Answer (score 2):

like this.

```
arr.push([['one','two','three']]);
```

Comment: That makes an array in an array in an array, i.e. the same as `var arr = [ [ ['one','two','three'] ] ];`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
var oldArray = new Array() // Put something inside

var newArray = {a:valueA, b:valueB, c:valueC}

oldArray.push(newArray)
```

Best